# Comparison between groups: no significance?

Tags: anova, nonparametric

I'm interested in finding differences in outcomes between groups. The residuals are not normal. I use Dunn test. Sample sizes are small (50 samples in 4 groups). I do multiple testing (different divisions into groups) - it is meaningful.

1. Often there are significantly different comparisons between groups (Wilcoxon test, moreover some of these comparisons were reported before and thus are likely to be real), but the test overall has quite large p-value. Should the trick "look at this interesting subgroup analysis" be forbidden?
2. Several times I've noticed that when one of the groups is small (couple of observations), Dunn test result remains insignificant even if there is a very small between-groups p-value. Should I disregard small groups before comparison?

Comment: What test is "Wilcox test"?

Comment: Sorry, that's stupid slang from R. Mann-Whitney two-sample rank based comparison.

Comment: Ah, yes, in R, - for what I think are poor reasons - they abbreviated Wilcoxon, dropping the last two letters. Unfortunately they abbreviated it to an existing name (and worse, it happens to be the name of several people who've done work in statistics). It was possible for them to allow `wilcox` as an acceptable abbreviation of `wilcoxon` but instead the way they did it the correct name doesn't work at all.